# Set Index Name in Django with db_index=True

Tags: django, django-models

Can I set my own index name when setting index using db_index=True in Django models?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    class Meta:
        indexes = models.Index(fields=['field'], name='index-name')
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify the field as an attribute in the dot format instead of string to make refactoring in the future easier? I didn't want to use this method because of this problem.